# Using .position() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, offset

My script [here](http://jsbin.com/ixihej/13/edit) needs a little work on the positioning of the sentence. If you click on any of the choices, the sentence should slide down to that height. I'm trying to use `.position()` to obtain a relative position (as the doc says, relative to the offset parent, which is why I'm writing this thread).

Obviously, the `.position()` is a little off right now because it seem to think it's offset parent is the document itself and the jQuery doc didn't mention anything about setting the offset parent. Any inputs are greatly appreciated.

PS: I'm currently using `position: relative` on the sentence, which are 2 `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on css add `position: relative;` to the parent element/container

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` to your CSS for `div[id^=wrapper]`.

All absolute positions are taken *relative to the closest positioned container.* In your original code, the closest positioned container is the `<body>` tag, which obviously isn't what you want.